# Create a list from a static method result

Tags: c#, list

I have the following snippet of code bellow. I would like to display the result of the new list once `FindEvenNumber(numbers)` is called in the `Main()`.

Not sure how to do this..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 34 };
    //You can just call a static method you don't have to instantiate.
   FindEvenNumber(numbers);
}


public static List<int> FindEvenNumber(List<int> evenNumbers)
{
    List<int> evenNumbersNew = new List<int>();
    foreach (int ij in evenNumbers)
    {
        if (ij % 2 == 0)
            evenNumbersNew.Add(ij);
    }
    return evenNumbersNew;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop your list, but I would use a one-liner

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", FindEvenNumber(numbers)));
```

You can even emded *FindEvenNumber* into this one-liner using Linq.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers.Where(i => i % 2 == 0)));
```

Comment: You should add also the same with steps as OP (and maybe future readers) can be a beginner.

Comment: @Sehnsucht I should? No, I think there will be other answers showing it....

Comment: +1 I just suggest add the references: [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) and [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

In the main, you can replace the line

```
FindEvenNumber(numbers);
```

with

```
System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", FindEvenNumber(numbers)));
```

In addition, if you don't need a List, I'd suggest to change your method to:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> FindEvenNumber(List<int> evenNumbers)
    {
        foreach (int ij in evenNumbers)
        {
            if (ij % 2 == 0)
                yield return ij;
        }
    }
```

where the keyword `yield` does the job for you.
Another suggestion is to use `HashSet` instead of `List` if you want the numbers to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers provided seem to be assuming the O.P. has full knowledge of string.Join and even LINQ. I'm providing this answer as the O.P. may not understand those concepts, yet.

The question restated is:

> How do I get the results of a method and then use those results?

Let's break down the Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // a new List has bee created with a set of integers
   List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 34 };

   // the numbers List is now being provided to the FindEvenNumber method,
   // but the results of the method are not used.
   FindEvenNumber(numbers);

   // To store the results of FindEvenNumber:
   List<int> evenNumbers = FindEvenNumber(numbers);

   // To use the results, loop over each item:
   foreach(int i in evenNumbers)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. The original `numbers` List is never modified, it is simply given to `FindEvenNumber` which returns a new List.
2. There is no need to call .ToString() against the integer due to [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) doing that for you.

#### Using string.Join

We can take this a bit further if the goal is to:

- print out everything returned from `FindEvenNumber`
- use a comma to separate the numbers being printed.

Instead of using a foreach loop and calling Console.WriteLine inside the loop, we can use the .NET [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method to Join the contents of a collection into a single string:

```
// To store the results of FindEvenNumber:
List<int> evenNumbers = FindEvenNumber(numbers);

// store the results of string.Join into a local variable:
string myNumbers = string.Join(",", evenNumbers);

// print the string to the Console:
Console.WriteLine(myNumbers);
```

#### Using LINQ

An alternative to using the static method of `FindEvenNumber`, we can take advantage of LINQ to project the original list into a new list while invoking an anonymous method within the LINQ statement:

```
IEnumerable<int> evenNumbers = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

All we've done in the above is take the logic from `FindEvenNumber` and move it into a LINQ expression that says:

> For Each integer in the `numbers` list (represented by x), find the
>   numbers that are divisible by 2 with a remainder of 0.

In the original `FindEvenNumber`, the logic was: `ij % 2 == 0`; the logic is exactly the same in the LINQ version, but `ij` is now represented by `x` in the LINQ version.

#### Briging all concepts together

Now that everything has been explained, the concepts can be brought together:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // a new List has bee created with a set of integers
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 34 };

    // store the results of string.Join into a local variable:
    string myNumbers = string.Join(",", numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0));

    // print the string to the Console:
    Console.WriteLine(myNumbers);
}
```

And if you wanted to be even more compact:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // a new List has bee created with a set of integers
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 34 };

    // print the string to the Console:
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)));
}
```

Comment: In all details, you forgot to show how `string.Join(",", evenNumbers);
` could be implemented  using classical loops :)

Comment: @EZI - ha! Even funnier that it took me about 30 seconds to pick up on the humor... :)